# Creating a login for PowerBI dashboard?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I need to create a dashboard but I don't want it to be seen by everyone and I need to create a login form for that.

Option 1 : I can create a asp.net page for login and after successful login I can show the dashboard.

Option 2: Which I want to know that- Does PowerBI contains some login kind of functionality so that I don't need to upload a .net web page !!

Can someone provide me the link or tutorial for the same?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You could create a group workspace and only add the users who are allowed to see the dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

```
Option 1 : I can create a asp.net page for login and after successful login I can show the dashboard.
```

This wouldn't work because if the person knew the URL of the page, they wouldn't need to defer to your ASP.NET login page and just go straight for the source (once they found out the URL).

The only way I know you can manage private dashboards is by creating workspaces within Power BI which you can provision access to certain users or accounts. This requires you to upgrade to Power BI Pro however and is not offered in the free version.